# Differentiate table rows with same class, id and parent classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

> **Background:**
>
> I am developing clientside on a teamplace .NET website with Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2010 editing possibilities. However, I don't have access to any code-behind due to security precautions. Therefore I cannot directly pass data from server to client. Thus I must use the standard webparts to get the stored data to the current page and then get and set the values to my own implemented html code. I will then hide the webparts.
>
> This is why I can only accomplish what I am aiming for by using javascript.

I cannot change or add any attribute to any element within this rendered code. The following is the infrastructure I recreated (by using developer tools) that resembles the actual rendered html code (it has **a lot** of additional attributes):

```
<div id="WebPartWPQ7">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr"></tr>

                            <tr class="ms-itmhover">
                                <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"></td>
                                <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                                    <a href="http://www.google.com">Example link</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover">
                                <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"></td>
                                <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                                    <a href="http://www.google.com">Example link 2</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="ms-itmhover">
                                <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"></td>
                                <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                                    <a href="http://www.google.com">Example link 3</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my own code where I want to append links for every value of the table rows second column.

```
<ul id="frLinks">
        <li class="lTitle">
            <strong>Related Links</strong>
        </li>

</ul>
```

I want to take the href and text content from every `a` tag contained on the second table cell of every table row.
This is my attempt:

```
var rowCount = $('#WebPartWPQ7 table tbody tr td table tbody tr').length;

for (i = 0; i < rowCount-1; i++) { //not appending to title row
    var relatedLinkText = $("#WebPartWPQ7 table tbody tr td table tbody .ms-itmhover .ms-vb-lastCell a").html();
    var relatedLink = $("#WebPartWPQ7 table tbody tr td table tbody .ms-itmhover .ms-vb-lastCell a").attr("href");
    $("#frLinks").append( '<a href="' + relatedLink + '"><li>' + relatedLinkText + '</li></a>');
}
```

My question is how do I differentiate these links when I'm getting them from the table. In this case it understandably always takes the first one and appends to list. My goal is to get each one and add it to my list, but how?

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6eo830w/) for more clarity.

I am aware of the inefficiency and inflexibility of my descendant selectors, if you are willing to share a better overall alternative I would be glad.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ozq5jt8a/1/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ozq5jt8a/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('#WebPartWPQ7 table tbody tr td table tbody tr').each(function(){
  var $a = $(this).find("td:eq(1) a").clone();
  $("#frLinks").append($("<li/>").append($a));
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/c6eo830w/4/)

Comment: Really smooth solution, thank you! But as it is now it will append the same links again if you refresh page. I want it to always only show the actual number of links. Do you know how I could accomplish that control? I have tried with localStorage without result.

Comment: I didn't get you, if you refresh the page the entire thing will be refreshed and you should get the same result. How will it show different number of links..? You might want to post a different question explaining the scenario if you're using any framework or something...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.ms-itmhover').each(function(){
link = $(this).find('td.ms-vb-lastCell').html();
$("#frLinks").append('<li>'+link+'</li>');
})
```

This will get all links and append to your code. 
I have updated your JSFiddle example here [JSFiddleUpdate](http://jsfiddle.net/c6eo830w/3/)